# EF Core for CosmosDB: OwnsMany for collection of same type as entity throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

We currently testing to use EF Core for Cosmos instead of the client. We have an Entity like this, which has an collection of same type as the entity (Collection2):

```cs
public class MyCosmosEntity
{
    public Guid id { get; set; }
    public List<SomeOtherType> Collection1 { get; set; } = new();
    public List<MyCosmosEntity> Collection2 { get; set; } = new();
    //some more properties..
}
```

The problem is to load the Data of the second collection. For the first collection `OwnsMany` works fine.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // some other stuff

    modelBuilder.Entity<MyCosmosEntity>()
        .OwnsMany(o => o.Collection1);
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyCosmosEntity>()
        .OwnsMany(o => o.Collection2);
}
```

But for the second it throws an `InvalidOperationException` if we try to load some data like below:

`The entity type 'MyCosmosEntity' cannot be configured as owned because it has already been configured as a non-owned. If you want to override previous configuration first remove the entity type from the model by calling 'Ignore'.  See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-owned for more information.`

```cs
try
{
    var test = await _cosmosDbContext.TestEntitiesContainer
        .Where(_ => _.OrderId == orderId)
        .ToListAsync();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
            
}
```

Without `OwnsMany` for `Collection2` throws no Exception, but the `Collection2` collection is empty. Is there a way to configure an Collection/Property to have the same type as the entity?

(For the Cosmos Client, it is no problem.)